# Ms access autoNumber when retrieving data

Tags: netbeans-7

can anyone help with retrieving value from ms access db

the problem with auto number, I want to show it in Jtextfield when I click over a record into the table..
I asked before this question, but no one answer me.
Please help me with this problem as soon as posible.

```
try {
    int row = table_BP.getSelectedRow();
    String Table_Clicked = table_BP.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    String sql = "Select * from Blood_pressure where Patient_Id='" + Table_Clicked + "'";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        try {
            String add1 = rs.getString("BP_Test_ID").toString();
            txt_testNo.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getString("Patient_Id");
            txt_PID.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getString("Date_Of_test");
            DC_Date.setDateFormatString(add3);
            String add4 = rs.getString("Blood_presure");
            txt_BP.setText(add4);
            String add5 = rs.getString("Remarks");
            TA_Remarks.setText(add5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sdsdsd");

        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an exception? What goes wrong in your code?

Comment: Can you share us the whole class or method ? `@user3265292`

Comment: I got Message says" Microsoft [ Odbc Microsft Access driver] Data type mismatch in criteria experssion